# Using associate() method won't work (BadMethodCallException)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to `associate` my **Document** model current id from view using **Comment** model. But after hitting the button. It always says.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

**CommentController**

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{

    public function postComments(Request $request, Document $document)
    {

        $this->validate($request,
        [
            'comment' => 'required',
        ]);

        $document = Document::find($document);

        $commentObject = new Comment();

        $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;
        $commentObject->associate($document);
        $commentObject->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I'm trying here to get the current `id` of the model from view so I can associate this in my `$commentObject`.

**DocumentController**

```
//READ
public function readDocuments($id)
{
    //Find the document in the database and save as var.
    $document = Document::find($id);

    return view ('document.read')->with('document', $document);
}
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/document/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.read',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

This is where I get the current id of the view.

```
//COMMENT
Route::post('/document/{document}/comments',
[
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@postComments',
'as' => 'comments',
]);
```

**View**

```
<div class = "col-md-6">

    <div class = "form-group">

        <textarea id = "content">{{ $document->content }}</textarea>

    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">

        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Approve</button>

    </div>
</div>

<!--COMMENT CONTROLLER-->
<div class = "col-md-6">                                        
    <form class = "form-vertical" method = "post" action = "{{ url('/document/'.$document->id.'/comments') }}">

        <div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

            <label for = "comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "4" id = "comment" name = "comment" placeholder = "Leave a feedback"></textarea>

            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</span>
            @endif

        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Comment</button>

        </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
</div>
```

I think I'm having a error in my **CommentController** because when I tried to **save** or **insert**. I think it cannot get the current id of the model. Any help or tips? Thanks!

**Update**

Models:

**Comment**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $tables = 'comments';

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'comment',
        'document_id',
    ];

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document');
    }
}
```

**Document**

```
class Document extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'documents';

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'title',
        'content',
        'category_id',
    ];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `associate()` method is supposed to be applied on relations.

I believe (considering you `Comment` Model has `documents` relation), you should use

```
$commentObject->documents()->associate($document);
```

Furthermore, I believe your method should be as follows..

```
public function postComments(Request $request, Document $document)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    //No need to do the following - Laravel 5.2 will Model Bind it because of Document $document in parameters above
    //$document = Document::find($document);

    $commentObject = new Comment();

    $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;

    $document->comments()->save($commentObject);
    //..other tasks


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

`$document->comments()` is a query builder and when you pass it the `->save($comment)` , it updates the `$comment` object's `document_id` property and sets it to the `$document->id` , that is the `id` of the `$document` object calling this query. And then saves the `$comment` object.

Comment: How can I `associate()` the `document_id` (foreign key) that linked to my Comments model? Please see my updated post..I got an error it says. `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'documents_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `documents_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hahaha, , 2016-07-28 15:40:22, 2016-07-28 15:40:22))`

Comment: Wow! I just wow! It works!! I'm little bit confused here. `$document->comments()->save($commentObject);` Can you tell something about this?

Comment: `$document` is accessing the property of `comments()` in my Document model. How this determine by getting the `document_id`? I'm little confuse here.

Comment: @francisunoxx read it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) .. If still confused, let me know

Comment: Thanks for the info. Correct me if I'm wrong. It called here the comments() method to obtain the instance of relationship and this will automatically get the foreign key that your reference?  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes..!! It called here the `comments()` method to obtain the instance of relationship and this will automatically get the `foreign key` from the object calling the `comments()` method

Comment: Oh how cool the laravel are and the `$document` is the instance of Document Controller? Am I right? :)

Comment: no... $document is the instance of Document Model..I think you should follow [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) tutorial once and [this one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate) afterwards.

Comment: I already get it! Thanks for this. I'm gonna follow your steps. :)